# WYSIWYG or WYSIWYM for trac?

Tags: trac, wysiwyg

How do I go about setting up some kind of WYSIWY* input for Trac? I found [this](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WysiWyg) page, but that seems to be just a list of ideas/possibilities. I also found [this](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TinyMceWikiPlugin), but that seems to be out of date (it mentions a patch for 0.10 - I'm on 0.11), plus it uses TinyMCE, which isn't my favorite, and outputs HTML, not WikiCode.

Any better options out there?

Answer (score 2):

I have not found any excellent solutions to WYSIWYG with Trac.  I have tried [TracWysiwygPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracWysiwygPlugin) as Remy suggests, but it has its problems.  It is much more limited than the actual rendering engine, and it has the nasty habit of killing your entire edit if you manage to find one of the edge cases where your markup is incomprehensible to it.

After about a week of frustration, I switched back to just using plain markup and haven't missed WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 1):

The [TracWysiwygPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracWysiwygPlugin) would be another option.